# How to write a custom stdandardization layer with tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-layer, tf.keras

currently I am building my first neural networks with tensorflow and keras API.
I want to write a Layer for standardization of the input, because doing it in the preprocess could lead to errors when the model is used after training.
Therefor I want to pass my training dataset to the init function of that Layer and calculate the mean and standard deviation.

The Problem is that I also want to save and load the model after training. But if I call load_model(modelname) I would get an error because the init function expects the training data as an argument. Furthermore I am not sure if its correct to specify the mean and std as a tf.Variable or if there is a better way to do it, such that these values get loaded when using load_model/load_weights.

I'm happy for every answer.

The following code represents the basic idea for such a layer.

```
class stdLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, train_x, trainable=False,**kwargs):
        super(stdLayer, self).__init__(trainable=trainable,**kwargs)
        means=np.mean(train_x,axis=0)
        stds=np.std(train_x,axis=0)
        self.means = tf.Variable(means,
                                dtype=tf.float32,
                                name="means",
                                trainable=False)
        self.stds = tf.Variable(stds,
                                dtype=tf.float32,
                                name="stds",
                                trainable=False)


    def call(self, input):
        input_st = (input-self.means)/self.stds
        return input_st
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could just have a `BatchNormalization` layer at the start of your model.

In all cases, though, you need that your production data is in the same format as the training data.

---

Alternatively, instead of passing the training data, pass only `means` and `stds`.

```
class StdLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, means, stds, trainable=False,**kwargs):
        ...
        self.means_init = means
        self.stds_init = stds
        ...

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.means = self.add_weight(name='means', 
                                      shape=self.means_init.shape,
                                      initializer='zeros',
                                      trainable=True) 
                                       #if you put false here, they will never be trainable
        self.stds =  self.add_weight(name='stds', 
                                      shape=self.stds_init.shape,
                                      initializer='ones',
                                      trainable=True)
                                      #if you put false here, they will never be trainable

        keras.backend.set_value(self.means, self.means_init)
        keras.backend.set_value(self.stds, self.stds)

        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        ...

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        ...

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'means_init': self.means_init,
            'stds_init': self.stds_init,
        }
        base_config = super(StdLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if numpy arrays can be passed to `config`.
You can maybe use `__init__(self, means=None, stds=None, ...`, and put an `if` inside `build` for the `set_values`. Find another way to calculate the shapes in `add_weight` and you can get rid of the `config` vars.

Comment: That would probably be the easiest way, but wouldn't it be smarter to set the mean and std from the beginning if I already know them? Can you tell me if the values of all Layer attributes of type tf.Variable get automatically saved when I do model.save() or model.save_weights()?

Comment: No, you must follow Keras documentation and use `add_weight` inside `build`.